# How to select values within the range vector?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, vector

Good afternoon, I am a beginner in r

I have two variables

```
x <- c (5,7,10,28,31,55)
y <- c(1:6, 8:11, 29:34)

# i would like to select the variable **x** when it comes with in the range of variable **y**
```

What i tried is that

```
 for ( i in x){
  if (i >= y[1] & i <= y[2]){
  print (paste(y[1] , i))
    }
}
# My expected output is print(paste(y[1], i)) Means 1,5 and 8,10 like that

1,5
8,10 # I want my output like that. can anyone Please help me.
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. What you you mean with "select variable a with in the range of variable b"? And what is ```y```  ?

Comment: I changed it. I want to select the x values when it is with in the range of y. To be more clear, 5 present within y (first position) 1:6 right so i want to select 5 along with 1. followed by 10 is the value of x and y(second position) is 8:11 so i am trying to print 10 and 8.  If you still did not get my point just ask me. I can explain

Answer (score 1):

If you did store your range values in a list, such as:

```
y <- list(1:6, 8:11, 29:34)
```

You could also try the following to see if an element in vector `x` is contained in the list `y`, and if so, print the minimum value of the range and the element:

```
for (i in x) {
  lapply(y, function(j) {
    if(i %in% j) print(paste(min(j), i, sep = ','))
  })
}
```

**Output**

```
[1] "1,5"
[1] "8,10"
[1] "29,31"
```

---

An alternative method could include storing your range values in a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  lower = c(1, 8, 29),
  upper = c(6, 11, 34)
)
```

Then, you can do a `merge` with `x` and your data.frame and `subset` when `x` values are between the lower and upper values.

```
result <- subset(merge(x, df), x >= lower & x <= upper)
```

Then, you can write the result to a csv file:

```
write.csv(file = "output.csv", result[ , c("lower", "x")], row.names = FALSE)
```

In this case, it writes out the minimum value of the range `lower` and the value of `x` (comparable with desired output).

Comment: @Rengaraj See edited answer, which also allows for csv output. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I used write with append = TRUE to save as a txt file. That also works.

Comment: @Ben: great answer! I am struggling to define ranges for functions  - can you please take a look at this question here if you  have time?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68280857/r-x-probs-outside-0-1 thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This loop does what you want as near as I can understand it

```
x <- c(5,7,10,28,31,55)
y <- cbind(c(1,8,29),c(6,11,34))

for ( i in x){
  test <- which(i >= y[,1] & i <= y[,2])
  if (length(test)>0){
    print (paste(y[test,1] , i,sep=","))
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
"1,5"
"8,10"
"29,31"
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But i have one more question. My "y" are range values. I don't know how to supply. Is there any way to supply as a list (mylist <- list ((10:15), (20:25), (30:35))) ? Just asking.

Comment: Sure, you can use a range of values but for this problem it seemed that you were only interested in the min and max of each range of values containing the x values. To use a list you could create another inner for loop to test the min and max of each range in the list, but it seems unnecessary.

Comment: okay, i understand that. Once again thanks

Comment: How do i export this value into csv format. Because the print function comes so is there any way?